# how to identify people's relationship based on name, address and then assign a same ID through linux comman or Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have one csv file.

```
D,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,snapshot,Address
2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,201211.0,J
3,David,HM,Lee,M,1991,201211.0,J
6,66M,,Rock,F,1990,201211.0,J
0,David,H M,Lee,M,1990,201211.0,B
3,Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,C
6,Marc,M,Robert,M,1988,201211.0,C
6,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,D
```

I want to assign persons with same last name living in the same address a same ID or index. It's better that ID is made up of only numbers.
If persons have different last name in the same place, then ID should be different. 
Such ID should be unique. Namely, people who are different in either address or last name, ID must be different. 
My expected output is

```
D,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,snapshot,Address,ID
2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,201211.0,J,11
3,David,HM,Lee,M,1991,201211.0,J,12
6,66M,,Rock,F,1990,201211.0,J,11
0,David,H M,Lee,M,1990,201211.0,B,13
3,Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,C,14
6,Marc,M,Robert,M,1988,201211.0,C,14
6,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,D,15
```

My datafile size is around 30 GB. I am thinking of using `groupBy` function in spark based on the key consisting of `LNAME` and `address` to group those observations together. Then assign it a ID by key. But I don't know how to do this. After that, maybe I can use `flatMap` to split the line and return those observations with a ID. But I am not sure about it. In addition, can I also make it in Linux environment? Thank you.

Comment: This is beginner awk homework.  Give it a try, you can't figure out something specific show how far you got and ask about that.  At least show a plan for what to do and ask about some step in that plan.

Comment: For pyspark you need a [Window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) and a [rank function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank).

Comment: @jthill Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question. I am a beginner of `awk` so I am not clear how to use it to resolve my issue.

Comment: this is actually a very good question if you removed the `linux` and `awk` tags. awk is simply not a right tool to parse CSV files when it's 30GB containing fields like address.

Comment: @jxc Thank you for your comment. The reason why I wanna try linux environment is because doing my work could not use spark parallelization function and it may be faster to run it using `awk` under `linux`.

Comment: @Samson, unless your CSV files had been normalized, i.e. removed special characters like comma, newline from inside the field. splitting the CSV fields itself can be complex and error-prone. better using a CSV-library to parse the csv file if you insist on doing it under shell.

Comment: @jxc I see. Would you mind giving me some specific ideas on how to do my work in other environment? Thank you.

Comment: @Samson, with pyspark, you can do something like `df.repartition(100,'LNAME', 'Address').withColumn(sid, F.spark_partition_id()).rdd.mapPartitions(f, True)`. where you divide your data into smaller chunks based on two columns, and run pure Python code within mapPartitions() to attached an `idx` to each Row. convert the result back to dataframe and you can then merge idx, spark_partition_id and generate a sequence ids on the whole data-set.

Comment: The idea is to (1) divide the large dataset into small chunks with related Rows in the same partition. (2) on each partition with smaller dataset, do regular Python coding to attach idx to each Row. (3) merge partition-based idx with spark_partition_id, max_idx on each spark_partition_id to create the final id for all dataset.

Comment: if you can load all your data into RAM, then just try any programming languages Perl, Python etc with a CSV library to load the data. then do a sorting and looping.

Comment: @jxc Thanks a lot for such detailed information. Sounds cool. I will try later. Then tell you the result.

Comment: @jxc Sorry to work late. I applied your method under pyspark. But there are some issues occurred. First, `repartition(100,'LNAME', 'Address')` means partitioning the original dataframe into 100 partitions. It's correct? Since there are millions of different pairs of "LNAME" and "Address". I was wondering it's okay to just repartition 100. Especially, the final id is related to the partition. And when I ran `withColumn(sid, F.spark_partition_id())`, it warned that "F" is not defined. The final issue is that if I assign an idx to each row, then how to people's relationship.

Comment: @jxc Continued. Even if assigning the same id to the same partition, the total number of partitions may be not enough to guarantee that only one type of pair "LNAME" and "Address" is in one partition, given that my data is large.  Would you mind writing down the full command to complete the work?  Thank you.

Comment: @Samson, the `100` is the number of buckets for the hash partitioning (i.e. hash_value%100), so many of the LName+Address combos will fall into the same partitions. this is a number you need to tweak based on your actual data. you may also need to add a third column to help relieve the skewness if exists. also use mapPartitionsWithIndex(), so there is no need for the spark_partition_id(). I will check this back tomorrow if possible as it's now Friday evening at my local time.

Comment: @Samson, we just need to make sure the same LNAME+Address are in the same partition. no need to guarantee one LNAME+Address combo to one partition. however, we do need to worry about the potential skewness of the generated hashing values.

Comment: Many thanks. No worries.

Comment: @Samson, added some code to describe the method I mentioned, let me know if there are any problems in running the code. Also, I removed awk/linux from the tags which works only when the whole data can be loaded into RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the basic idea is to partition the data properly so that records with the same *LNAME+Address* stay in the same partition, run Python code to generate separate *idx* on each partition and then merge them into the final *id*.

**Note:** I added some new rows in your sample records, see the result of `df_new.show()` shown below.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, sum as fsum, col, max as fmax, lit, broadcast

# ...skip code to initialize the dataframe 

# tweak the number of repartitioning N based on actual data size
N = 5

# Python function to iterate through the sorted list of elements in the same 
# partition and assign an in-partition idx based on Address and LNAME.
def func(partition_id, it):
  idx, lname, address = (1, None, None)
  for row in sorted(it, key=lambda x: (x.LNAME, x.Address)):
    if lname and (row.LNAME != lname or row.Address != address): idx += 1
    yield Row(partition_id=partition_id, idx=idx, **row.asDict())
    lname = row.LNAME
    address = row.Address

# Repartition based on 'LNAME' and 'Address' and then run mapPartitionsWithIndex()
# function to create in-partition idx. Adjust N so that records in each partition
# should be small enough to be loaded into the executor memory:
df1 = df.repartition(N, 'LNAME', 'Address') \
        .rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(func) \
        .toDF()
```

Get number of unique rows `cnt` (based on Address+LNAME) which is `max_idx` and then grab the running SUM of this rcnt.

```
# idx: calculated in-partition id
# cnt: number of unique ids in the same partition: fmax('idx')
# rcnt: starting_id for a partition(something like a running count): coalesce(fsum('cnt').over(w1),lit(0))
# w1: WindowSpec to calculate the above rcnt
w1 = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('partition_id').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,-1)

df2 = df1.groupby('partition_id') \
         .agg(fmax('idx').alias('cnt')) \
         .withColumn('rcnt', coalesce(fsum('cnt').over(w1),lit(0)))

df2.show()
+------------+---+----+
|partition_id|cnt|rcnt|
+------------+---+----+
|           0|  3|   0|
|           1|  1|   3|
|           2|  1|   4|
|           4|  1|   5|
+------------+---+----+
```

Join df1 with df2 and create the final id which is `idx + rcnt`

```
df_new = df1.join(broadcast(df2), on=['partition_id']).withColumn('id', col('idx')+col('rcnt'))

df_new.show()
#+------------+-------+---+----+-----+------+------+-----+---+--------+---+----+---+
#|partition_id|Address|  D| DOB|FNAME|GENDER| LNAME|MNAME|idx|snapshot|cnt|rcnt| id|
#+------------+-------+---+----+-----+------+------+-----+---+--------+---+----+---+
#|           0|      B|  0|1990|David|     M|   Lee|  H M|  1|201211.0|  3|   0|  1|
#|           0|      J|  3|1991|David|     M|   Lee|   HM|  2|201211.0|  3|   0|  2|
#|           0|      D|  6|2000| Marc|     M|Robert|   MS|  3|201211.0|  3|   0|  3|
#|           1|      C|  3|2000| Marc|     M|Robert|    H|  1|201211.0|  1|   3|  4|
#|           1|      C|  6|1988| Marc|     M|Robert|    M|  1|201211.0|  1|   3|  4|
#|           2|      J|  6|1991|  66M|     F|   Rek| null|  1|201211.0|  1|   4|  5|
#|           2|      J|  6|1992|  66M|     F|   Rek| null|  1|201211.0|  1|   4|  5|
#|           4|      J|  2|1995|  66M|     F|  Rock|    J|  1|201211.0|  1|   5|  6|
#|           4|      J|  6|1990|  66M|     F|  Rock| null|  1|201211.0|  1|   5|  6|
#|           4|      J|  6|1990|  66M|     F|  Rock| null|  1|201211.0|  1|   5|  6|
#+------------+-------+---+----+-----+------+------+-----+---+--------+---+----+---+

df_new = df_new.drop('partition_id', 'idx', 'rcnt', 'cnt')
```

### Some notes:

- Practically, you will need to clean-out/normalize the column *LNAME* and *Address* before using them as uniqueness check. For example, use a separate column `uniq_key` which combine *LNAME* and *Address* as the unique key of the dataframe. see below for an example with some basic data cleansing procedures:

  ```
  from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, lit, concat_ws, upper, regexp_replace, trim

  #(1) convert NULL to '': coalesce(col, '')
  #(2) concatenate LNAME and Address using NULL char '\x00' or '\0'
  #(3) convert to uppercase: upper(text)
  #(4) remove all non-[word/whitespace/NULL_char]: regexp_replace(text, r'[^\x00\w\s]', '')
  #(5) convert consecutive whitespaces to a SPACE: regexp_replace(text, r'\s+', ' ')
  #(6) trim leading/trailing spaces: trim(text)
  df = (df.withColumn('uniq_key',
      trim(
        regexp_replace(
          regexp_replace(
            upper(
              concat_ws('\0', coalesce('LNAME', lit('')), coalesce('Address', lit('')))
            ),
            r'[^\x00\s\w]+',
            ''
          ),
          r'\s+',
          ' '
        )
      )
  ))
  ```

  Then in the code, replace `'LNAME'` and `'Address'` with `uniq_key` to find the idx
- As mentioned by **cronoik** in the comment, you can also try one of the Window rank functions to calculate the in-partition idx. for example:

  ```
  from pyspark.sql.functions import spark_partition_id, dense_rank

  # use dense_rank to calculate the in-partition idx
  w2 = Window.partitionBy('partition_id').orderBy('LNAME', 'Address')
  df1 = df.repartition(N, 'LNAME', 'Address') \
          .withColumn('partition_id', spark_partition_id()) \
          .withColumn('idx', dense_rank().over(w2))
  ```

  After you have df1, use the same methods as above to calculate df2 and df_new. This should be faster than using `mapPartitionsWithIndex()` which is basically an RDD-based method.
- For your real data, adjust **N** to fit your actual data size. this `N` only influences the initial partitions, after dataframe join, the partition will be reset to default(200).   you can adjust this using `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` for example when you initialize the spark session:

  ```
  spark = SparkSession.builder \
                      ....
                      .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 500) \
                      .getOrCreate()
  ```

Comment: Thanks a million for such informative explanation. It worked well in my computer. But I have something unclear. First, what does it mean adding `**` in `**row.asDict()`? I know that `row.asDict()` is to make the row be dictionary format but unclear about **. Second is related to ***clean-out/normalize the column...* note. There is code ` coalesce('LNAME', lit('')), coalesce('Address', lit(''))`. Is it supposed to be ` coalesce(col('LNAME'), lit('')), coalesce(col('Address'), lit(''))`?. The final one is how to add another column representing the frequency of those observations.

Comment: Continued. My data is large so I guess it will be better to do it within partitions. So I tried to follow your logic. Use `df1 = df.repartition(N, 'LNAME', 'Address').withColumn('fre', count('LNAME').over(w2))`. But it doesn't yields what I want. Its outcome is the accumulated count value in each partition.  Would you mind giving me some advice?

Comment: @Samson, the `**` is used to unpack a dictionary and merge with other dicts(Python 3 only). This is used to merge existing keys in Row objects with two new ones: `partition_id` and `idx`. For newer version of Spark, most of the API functions can take `column_name` as argument which is the same as using col('col_name'). If using colname does not work for your Spark version, just adjust it to using col('col_name')

Comment: to calculate the count, you can try use `w3 = Window.partitionBy('LNAME', 'Address')` to replace `w2` in your code.

Comment: Thank you always. It works. I was wondering whether it is very costly to partition by `LNAME` and `Address` when it comes to a big data. Or is it more efficient comparing to that first use `reduceBy` to get the frequency data based on `LNAME` and `Address`, and then employ `join` to add the frequency into the original data file?

Comment: @Samson, dataframe API should be more efficient than using RDD-based functions (you can google `pyspark rdd vs dataframe`). repartition involves data shuffling which could be slow. the performance is also related to data skewness, your cluster and application configurations or numPartitions etc.

Comment: I see. I counted the number of unique pairs of `LNAME` and `Address` in my original data before. It reached over 1 million. Is it fine to set **N** to be a million number or one hundred thousand unit? What will be the appropriate number for `N`? And in terms of data skewness, do you have any idea to address this issue?

Comment: you don't need to have each unique pair on a single partition, that would be less efficient. depends on how many executor cores you can use(i.e. 20), you can for example take N = 20*300=6000, so each partition roughly has 5MB row, consider run a python code on your local with a 5MB data. what if you run 300 times the same code?

Comment: you can probably try the following to find if some partitions have too many rows (take top-10 partitions with count of rows): `df.repartition(N,'LNAME','Address').rdd.glom().map(len).takeOrdered(10, key=lambda x: -x)`

Comment: Thank you, again. I understand now. I don't have to set a very large **N**. I will make it dependent on how many cores I can use. I will make use of your code to identify if there are some partitions with too many rows. What if it does, how shall I fix it? Increasing partitions?

Comment: if there are skewness, adjust N to see if this can relieve some. or add another column to split the partition with too many rows. this could be a little bit tricky since you need to make sure the same LNAME+Address get the same value of the new column so they don't fall into different partitions. so for example, you add the first letter of LNAME as the extra column: `substring('LNAME', 1, 1)`. just do this on overcrowded partitions, set to constant for other partitions. you will need to have a better exploration/understanding first with your data though.

Comment: I see. It looks tricky for me. Would you mind telling me how to write commands such that the extra work will only be executed on those partitions with overcrowded rows, while keep others constant? I think it will help me a lot. Maybe my recent data does not require it but I think I will need to apply it in the future since that issue is not rare.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have 30GB of input data, you probably don't want something that'll attempt to hold it all in in-memory data structures. Let's use disk space instead.

Here's one approach that loads all your data into a sqlite database, and generates an id for each unique last name and address pair, and then joins everything back up together:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

csv="$1"
# Use an on-disk database instead of in-memory because source data is 30gb.
# This will take a while to run.
db=$(mktemp -p .)

sqlite3 -batch -csv -header "${db}" <<EOF
.import "${csv}" people
CREATE TABLE ids(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, lname, address, UNIQUE(lname, address));
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ids(lname, address) SELECT lname, address FROM people;
SELECT p.*, i.id AS ID
FROM people AS p
JOIN ids AS i ON (p.lname, p.address) = (i.lname, i.address)
ORDER BY p.rowid;
EOF

rm -f "${db}"
```

Example:

```
$./makeids.sh data.csv
D,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,snapshot,Address,ID
2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,201211.0,J,1
3,David,HM,Lee,M,1991,201211.0,J,2
6,66M,"",Rock,F,1990,201211.0,J,1
0,David,"H M",Lee,M,1990,201211.0,B,3
3,Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,C,4
6,Marc,M,Robert,M,1988,201211.0,C,4
6,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,D,5
```

---

> It's better that ID is made up of only numbers.

If that restriction can be relaxed, you can do it in a single pass by using a cryptographic hash of the last name and address as the ID:

```
$ perl -MDigest::SHA=sha1_hex -F, -lane '
   BEGIN { $" = $, = "," } 
   if ($. == 1) { print @F, "ID" }
   else { print @F, sha1_hex("@F[3,7]") }' data.csv
D,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,snapshot,Address,ID
2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,201211.0,J,5c99211a841bd2b4c9cdcf72d7e95e46b2ae08b5
3,David,HM,Lee,M,1991,201211.0,J,c263f9d1feb4dc789de17a8aab8f2808aea2876a
6,66M,,Rock,F,1990,201211.0,J,5c99211a841bd2b4c9cdcf72d7e95e46b2ae08b5
0,David,H M,Lee,M,1990,201211.0,B,e86e81ab2715a8202e41b92ad979ca3a67743421
3,Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,C,363ed8175fdf441ed59ac19cea3c37b6ce9df152
6,Marc,M,Robert,M,1988,201211.0,C,363ed8175fdf441ed59ac19cea3c37b6ce9df152
6,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,D,cf5135dc402efe16cd170191b03b690d58ea5189
```

---

Or if the number of unique lname, address pairs is small enough that they can reasonably be stored in a hash table on your system:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}
NR == 1 {
    print $0, "ID"
    next
}
! ($4, $8) in ids {
    ids[$4, $8] = ++counter
}
{
    print $0, ids[$4, $8]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sort -t, -k8,8 -k4,4 <<EOD | awk -F, '  $8","$4 != last { ++id; last = $8","$4 }
                                          { NR!=1 && $9=id; print }' id=9 OFS=,
D,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,snapshot,Address
2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,201211.0,J
3,David,HM,Lee,M,1991,201211.0,J
6,66M,,Rock,F,1990,201211.0,J
0,David,H M,Lee,M,1990,201211.0,B
3,Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,C
6,Marc,M,Robert,M,1988,201211.0,C
6,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,D
> EOD
D,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,snapshot,Address
0,David,H M,Lee,M,1990,201211.0,B,11
3,Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,C,12
6,Marc,M,Robert,M,1988,201211.0,C,12
6,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,D,13
3,David,HM,Lee,M,1991,201211.0,J,14
2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,201211.0,J,15
6,66M,,Rock,F,1990,201211.0,J,15
$
```